# Java Audio Streaming isn't Working, keep running into an error

Tags: java, audio-streaming, javasound

I'm following this Java tutorial, and I've come across how to play audio, I followed the exact steps to writing the code, however, despite this, I get an error message, I doubt the video is out of date considering it's only a month old, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Here's the code I've written:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, LineUnavailableException
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        File file = new File("bababooey.wav");
        AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioStream);

        clip.start();

        String response = sc.next();
    }
}
```

Here's the error message I keep getting:

```
"C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-15.0.1.9-hotspot\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=57472:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\1ando\Documents\Programming\Java\Complete Java Tutorial\Audio\out\production\Audio" Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Audio data < 0
    at java.desktop/com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.open(DirectAudioDevice.java:1086)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'd really appreciate a response, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than the fact you are missing **try/catch** to trap any exceptions, your code works for me.

Check your imports for [AudioInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html), [AudioSystem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html), [Clip](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html), [LineUnavailableException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/LineUnavailableException.html), and finally the [UnsupportedAudioFileException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/UnsupportedAudioFileException.html). All these classes should be part of the [javax.sound.sampled](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/package-summary.html) Package. Imports should be:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
```

The code could be something like this:

```
// Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);  // I don't understand why you are using Scanner!
AudioInputStream audioStream = null;
try {
    File file = new File("explosion.wav");
    audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        
    clip.open(audioStream);
    clip.start();
    //String response = sc.next(); // I don't understand why you are using Scanner!
}
catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex);
}
finally {
    try {
        if (audioStream != null) {
            audioStream.close();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: So all the imports are there, and I copied your code just to see if something with my code was wrong, but I'm still getting that same error, any other ideas?

Comment: Also, if it helps, I'm using JDK 15, do you think I should switch to 11 or 12 instead? Would that help?

Comment: I used Java8 and it works fine. You will need to look through the JavaDocs for the new Java 15 classes to see what changes might have been made (if any). Switching to an older JDK may be an alternative for you.

Comment: You may find [this to be an interesting read](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2077521/java-tip-24--how-to-play-audio-in-applications.html).

Comment: This is embarrassing, I'm pretty sure my problem was that I was trying to play a really short sound effect, basically one where the time stamp was 0:00 seconds long, I tried the same code again with a longer sound and got it to play. I really appreciate the help, thanks!